# frontpage get object's long type id from model.addAttribute lose precision

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Think there is a class named 'User'.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    private String username;

    //...get、set
}
```

Then i try to jump to user information edit page by following codes:

```
@GetMapping("edit")
public String edit(Model model, @RequestParam Long id) {
    model.addAttribute("entity", userService.findById(id));
    return "user/edit";
}
```

In "user/edit" page, i try to get the correct id value, but failed.The long type id's value always lose precision, like if id's value is "94105929343041536", what i get is "94105929343041540".

Comment: first thing to remark here, is that i don't see a `/` in `@GetMapping("edit")` ? shouldn't it be `@GetMapping("/edit")` ?

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID You can add "/" prefix or not.Both are OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever your frontpage is, there are a lot of problems with Javascript, JSON and Angular when dealing with large long values. Unfortunately, you cannot change the way those values are rounded. 
In any of those cases, I would recommend to use a converter to convert your long values to String when retrieving/storing (using something like an AttributeConverter).

```java
@Converter
public class LongStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Long, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Long value) {
        return Long.toString(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Long convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return Long.parseLong(dbData);
    }
}
```

And then you can add this over your id field:

```java
@Convert(converter = LongStringConverter.class)
```

There are some other converters available depending on your exact use case.

Comment: Your idea is right.Before call body.addAttribute method, i must convert Long type to String type.But your code maybe not work.

Comment: It was only an example depending on your use case, but you can also implement a Spring Converter and add it right in your WebMvcConfigurer (override addFormatters(FormatterRegistry)). This will automate the conversion in every request.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i can come up the final solution.I made an public utility class change the entity into Map.The key code is this `Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) JSONObject.parse(JSON.toJSONString(entity, SerializerFeature.WriteMapNullValue));`.Before this, i add the annotation named `@JSONField(serializeUsing = ToStringSerializer.class)` on the Long type property.Then i can change the Long type property into String type.